# Set variable calendarID in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, gcal

I'm having some trouble setting a variable CalendarID in the Google Apps Script for my spreadsheet (using sheet to sync to gcal).

So far I've come to:

```
enter code here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,6);
  var calendarId = sheet.range.getValue()

enter code here
```

With my gcal ID set in "G2" (hence getRange(2,6)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, G2 should be `sheet.getRange(2,7)` because A1 is (1,1). You can also use `sheet.getRange("G2")`.

Then your last line should be
`var calendarId = range.getValue()`
since `range` is separately user defined variable and not a property of `sheet` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

i found the culprit.
We need getDisplayValue() instead of getValue()